# Hoving IBM-Cloud bucket from one instance to another (both on the same account or each on a distinct account )

Tags: migration, ibm-cloud, rclone

I want to move a IBM cloud bucket from one Object storage instance to another. The destination instance may be on the same accoun ot on another account. Is it possible to do it by transfering ownership for both scenarios?

Or, Do I need to copy files from one to another using rclone? Which may take long time to be complated.

In Google Workspace, it is too easy to migrate data between Shared drives even on distinct account.
I'm looking for such a drag-n-drop solution on IBM cloud actually.

Thanks in advance

I looked for ownership options but couldn't find it.
I tried moving using rclone using --server-side, but it didn't work. It downloads from source and upload to the destination bucket which takes too long for huge files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy of the objects, similar to AWS S3, is going to be required.  A rclone example can be found here: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-region-copy

Comment: Thank you for the comment. As I understand, It must be downloaded from source then uploaded to destination. The server-side-move is not valid for S3 buckets.

Answer (score 0):

Possible with in Accounts and same account - Check this:
You can replicate objects across buckets in different accounts. You can also specify a different destination bucket for each rule in the configuration.

COS Instance --> Bucket --> Configuration --> Bucket Replication --> Create Bucket Replication Rule

Prequisite: Create Destination Bucket in the same/another COS instance.
Additional permissions will be setup during the replication setup process.